# Matplotlib: Minor ticks not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib

for some reason my minor ticks in my plot are not showing anymore. Yesterday, I still had them in and I just don't know what I changed such that they disappeared...

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=True)

font = font_manager.FontProperties(family='sans-serif', style='normal', size=16)

for (i, alpha) in enumerate(alpha_values_small):
    filt = data[
        (data["Topology"] == "UNIFORM") & 
        (data["HashingPowerDistribution"] == "UNIFORM") & 
        (data["CentralityMeasure"] == "RANDOM") &
        (data["Alpha"] == alpha)]
    axs.plot(
        1/filt["Gamma"],
        filt["OrphanBlockRate"],
        label=r"$\alpha = {}$".format(np.round(alpha, 2)),
        color=color_list[i],
        marker=marker_list[i],
        linestyle="",
        markersize=12,
        linewidth=1.5,
        markeredgewidth=2,
    )
axs.set_xscale("log")
axs.set_xlabel(r"$\lambda_{nd}$", fontfamily='sans-serif', fontsize=22)
axs.set_ylabel("Orphan block rate", fontfamily='sans-serif', fontsize=22)
axs.tick_params(which='major', direction="in", top=True, left=True, right=True, width=1.5, size=6, labelsize=16)
axs.tick_params(which='minor', direction="in", top=True, left=True, right=True, width=1, size=4, labelsize=16)
axs.legend(prop=font, frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

Does anyone know why it's not showing my minor ticks?

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: Do you use version control, like Git, so that you can check what you've changed?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not track the jupyter notebooks where I create my plots...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe minor ticks are visible only if there is enough space.

You may try to increase the figure size

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(..., figsize=(10,10))
```

or decrease the font size.